# trying to use 2 columns

Tags: python, if-statement

So basically the goal of this code is to report which ports on a group of devices are being utilized.

The code is as follows:

```
`$` file_name = input('Enter File Name: ') + str('.csv')
total_ports = 500

my_reader = csv.reader(open(file_name))
ctr = 0
for total_reserved in my_reader:
    if total_reserved[2] == 'Reserved':
        ctr += 1
print(ctr, 'out of ', total_ports, 'PLS ports are reserved')

my_reader = csv.reader(open(file_name))
ctr_pls0 = 0
for pls0 in my_reader:
    if pls0[0] == 'L1 switches/L1 Switch 10G PLS0.BLLAB/Blade01' and total_reserved[2]  == 'Reserved':
      ctr_pls0 += 1

print(ctr_pls0, 'of these', ctr, 'are pls0 ports') `$`
```

This gives me the following output...

```
Enter File Name: 31.05.2018
175 out of  500 PLS ports are reserved
0 of these 175 are pls0 ports

Process finished with exit code 0
```

`0 of these 175 are pls0 ports` This is where the issue lies, this line should be providing me with the amount of ports that are called *`'L1 switches/L1 Switch 10G PLS.BLLAB/Blade01'`* **AND** that are shown as *`'Reserved'`* as per the .csv file.

Any ideas of what this could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second loop you should be using `pls0[2]`, not `total_reserved[2]`. `total_reserved` contains the last line of the file from the first loop.

But there's no reason for two loops at all, just increment both variables in the first loop.

```
with csv.reader(open(file_name)) as my_reader:
    ctr = 0
    ctr_pls0 = 0
    for total_reserved in my_reader:
        if total_reserved[2] == 'Reserved':
            ctr += 1
            if total_reserved[0] == 'L1 switches/L1 Switch 10G PLS0.BLLAB/Blade01'
                ctr_pls0 += 1
print(ctr, 'out of ', total_ports, 'PLS ports are reserved')
print(ctr_pls0, 'of these', ctr, 'are pls0 ports') `$`
```

Comment: you sir, are a legend. Thank you!!